# Can you connect to a BotFramework bot in Unity using Directline?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I've created a reference in script to Universal.Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine in Visual Studio 2019 and everything looks fine but after I save and return to Unity, I get the following error:

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Universal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried adding a reference to 'Universal' by Creating an Assembly Definition Reference asset, but did not see Universal on the list of references to add.

I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the package on Nuget, and grab the DLLs (and any DLLs it depends on) and put them into Assets/Plugins

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/

if it has different folders/versions pick the Standard version

Comment: Yes, I could do that if I wanted to create a bot in Unity, but all I want to do is connect to an existing bot. That's okay. I can probably do it with the REST API.